# What happens to promoters or poisons during a catalyzed reaction?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, catalysis

> [Catalysts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalysis) are substances that influence reaction rates without undergoing changes in their mass and chemical composition, but may undergo physical changes.

Promoters, poison etc. affect the activity of the catalyst. What are some examples of promoters or poison undergoing a change (physical or chemical) during a chemical reaction?